# cakephp3.0 : multi level optgroup in select box from threaded find

Tags: cakephp

I want to show multilevel categories in select box in cakephp and the last level category should be selectable. I tried through `optgroup` and find threaded. The first level and second level are showing same level not as an indent.

```
$this->Categories->find('threaded');
```

Any help?

Comment: Please show more of the code. It is not clear how the line of code you show is related to the two levels that are not indented. Also, mark the code using the buttons (or indented four spaces).

Comment: The form helper uses the array *keys* as the titles for groups, but threaded just returns the records in a hierarchy.